# SED scripting - exclude self

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I would explain my issue but it is easier just to paste the code

test.sh

```
sed -i '/192.168.1.1/d' *
```

I want it to exclude itself in this search, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You could just put the script in a different directory.

Comment: I could but I'm working on an automated process that hides within a calc.exe using ADS, I am lazy so I'd rather it just be in the same directory

Comment: You should probably use `sed -i '/192\.168\.1\.1/d' *` so that it doesn't match `192.168.101.44`, and additionally see how you can anchor it to avoid matching `192.168.1.13`. This would have the weird side effect of not triggering the bug (though you should apply chepner's solution too).

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to use `bash`'s extended pattern syntax.

```
shopt -s extglob
sed -i '/192.168.1.1/d' !(test.sh)
```

The pattern `!(test.sh)` matches everything *except* `test.sh`.

Comment: Do you need to enable that with `shopt -s extglob`?

Comment: Yes; otherwise, you get a syntax error complaining about an unexpected `(` following the `!`, since it doesn't expect a subshell to be starting there.